# Error missing binary operator while preprocessor compiling C program

Tags: 18.04, gcc, c

I tried upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and compile a simple C program from the terminal with `gcc -o test test.c`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    printf("h\n");
}
```

but it threw a `missing binary operator before token "("` error.

```
in file included from /usr/local/include/features.h:375:0 
from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33 
from /usr/include/stdio.h:27 
from test.c:1

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdef.h:467:79: error :missing binary operator before token "(" 
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (4,8) || __glibc_clang_prereq (3,5)

In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:276:43: error: missing binary operator before token "(" 
#if defined __USE_XOPEN2K8 || __GLIBC_USE (LIB (LIB_EXT2)
```

gcc version 7.5.0

Comment: I notice the error message mentions a file in `/usr/local/include` (which would not be populated by default). Is the behaviour any different if you prioritize the standard header location ex. `gcc -I/usr/include -o test test.c` ?

Comment: `gcc -I/usr/include -o test test.c` gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

The current default version of gcc for 18.04 is 7.4, not 7.5. Run `find /usr/include/ -name "stdio.h"`. The results should include `/usr/include/stdio.h` and be similar but not necessarily identical to this:

```
$ find /usr/include/ -name "stdio.h"
/usr/include/bsd/stdio.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/7/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/8/tr1/stdio.h
```

If no results are returned run the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc build-essential
```

Comment: even I change from `#include <stdio.h>` to `#include "stdio.h"` I got the same error